# Surjective $*$-homomorphism is automatically bijective?

Tags: operator-algebras, banach-algebras

I had to prove some statements for two unital $C^*$ algebras $A, B$ and $\Phi: A \to B$ a surjective $*$-homomorphism. I started out the proof by stating

> By the rank-nullity theorem, $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as vector spaces. Because $\Phi$ respects the algebra operations, they are also isomorphic as $C^*$ algebras.

After this, the rest of the proof followed (very) easily. However, when checking my solution, I saw that it followed a much more difficult path. Therefore I doublechecked, but I do not seem to find any mistake, In hindsight it does feel a little 'too easy'.

Am I right in claiming the above?

Comment: Let $A=C[0,2]$ and $B=C[0,1].$ Then the restriction mapping is a surjective $*$-homomorphism, but not injective. The algebras are isomorphic, but a bijective mapping is defined in a different way.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: A more serious problem.may occur: the restriction mapping from $C([0,1]\cup [2,3])$ onto $C[0,1]$ is a surjective $*$-homomorphism,  but the algebras are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rank-nullity theorem only holds in the finite-dimensional case and so I can not apply it here. See the comments for counterexamples.